# How to remove the noise from a data series

Tags: python, scipy, filtering, signal-processing

I have a data series containing underlying noise, the plot of which is :

[image]

The issue is to remove the noise leaving the pattern which is raised above the lower level. The lower level is road surface and the protruding patterns are metalwork, think of them as drain covers or 'manholes'. The noise also appears to some extent in the patterns (see the middle one).
I cannot expect the road surface noise to go completely, asphalt is not flat it has texture (or it would be like ice) however the patterns are geometric in nature and are defined.

The x-axis is distance (meters), around one reading per mm, the y-axis is mm. Velocity can be considered constant.

Attempts to resolve this have been.

Savitzky–Golay filter. This reduces the resolution of the signal, rounding off the corners in the pattern. The pattern is reduced to a series of curves.

signal.medfilt (median filter) This does not reduce the pattern resolution but increasing the kernel size also rounds the corners while removing the noise to some extent.

Butterworth low pass or high pass, This flattens the data (plot) and I will need to measure the metalwork/pattern in the final filtered data.

Attempting to use a fourier transform approach has me completely puzzled as examples are of a form where, "we create noisy data, then take out the noise we created". I have the noisy data it just needs to disappear. Most of the frequencies are close together and are a bit random.

Is there a method to remove the noise (it's a combination of road surface and the laser scanning it) leaving the image of the metalwork.

The final requirement after this will be to measure the height (or amplitude) of the pattern and the distance between the peaks.

Suggestions as to where to explore next would be appreciated (correcting my thoughts are not a problem). More than one sequential step to do this is acceptable.

Comment: This looks like more of a signal processing question than a programming question. Consider https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Include data or this cannot be meaningfully answered. Also depict what good output should look like, even if this is hand-traced. Finally - show what you've tried. "StackOverflow is not a code-writing service"; we cannot be expected to write code _ex nihilo_.

Comment: I am not asking anybody to write code but suggest an approaches to the problem.

Comment: The data is extremely large and commercial. The centre pattern is a square/flat top ridge. I'm hoping for the result without the noise on the flat surfaces.

Comment: you could at least provide some dummy data for people to play with.

Comment: What do you actually care to extract? The start and end of the metalwork? How high the metalwork is off the road? All filtration strategies will impact these measurements differently, and it's important to know which measure needs to be the most accurate. For instance, if you only care about start and end, then do a high pass followed by a simple threshold test to keep sharp edges while losing "road height".

Comment: You could try EMA for reducing noise. That's my go-to. It's hard to say what the right answer is, because to me I don't know what parts of the graph are "noise" and what parts are "real data." With regard to Savitzky–Golay: have you tried reducing window size if it's removing too much real data?

Comment: Sorry for being so obtuse. The final act is to measure the size of the pattern on the top of the 'metalwork'. There are two square patterns of different resolutions and a saw tooth pattern. The depth and width of the troughs are needed. I can measure these when there is no noise and I have a dataset with no/little noise. We have multiple sources of this data and some are better than others as the equipment used for the measurement has improved over time. (I'm working on making the data available but there is confidentiality involved)